# Identify what in an existing spreadsheet is shifting the columns into view

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please can someone advise what in [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FoTIb5us6KcNJN5yJcFeT1IW8WMxBhJlRnFprtppeFk/edit?usp=sharing) is controlling an action.

In cell A3, if you change this digit from 1-12 (to represent a month of the year), you will see that all of the columns in view, shift accordingly.

I am trying to replicate this spreadsheet and whilst I appear to have replicated the formulas that I can see, when I change the month digit in this cell, my columns in view remain as B - AG instead of changing to those columns for the corresponding month (e.g 2 = Feb => AG - BK).

I have no idea what in the spreadsheet is making this happen and I am struggling to come up with a Google search that can provide the answer for me.

Was hoping there might be some spreadsheet formula experts on here that could quickly advise what I need to be looking at...

Comment: Check `Tools > Script Editor`, is there any code there?

Comment: Yes! Thanks @ross - there is, and it looks like it is exactly what I was after :)

Comment: Yep that did it, thanks so much. I can either delete my question or accept an answer if you add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's most likely a script running on your sheet in the background.

Check `Tools > Script Editor` and look for any code that could be doing this.